# Deleting all records from a Microsoft SQL Server table from before a certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would I go about deleting all records from a SQL Server table from before a certain date, where the date column is of `DATETIME` datatype?

An example datetime is `2011-09-21 08:21:22`.

Comment: Use the `<` operator.

Answer (score 0):

just specify the date & time in string literal in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format

```
DELETE from yourtable
WHERE  the_date_column < '2011-09-21 08:21:22'
```

EDIT : added below section

if date to delete is `2011-09-21` and you want to includes date like `2011-09-21 01:23`, then specify the date to delete as one day later `2011-09-22`

```
DELETE from yourtable
WHERE  the_date_column < '2011-09-22'
```

Comment: Yes. `FROM` is optional. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017